# Fancybox2 api open() ignores options?

Tags: fancybox-2

The fancybox2 docs for the API call open() says

```
$.fancybox.open( [group], [options] )
```

However the docs go into detail about [ group ] and say nothing about the format expected for the  [ options ]

Furthermore the options seem to be ignored.

When I use

$.fancybox.open([{ href : '#popup_panel' }], [ { 'title' : 'Title Two', 'minWidth' : 500  }] );

or

$.fancybox.open([{ href : '#popup_panel' }], [ { title : 'Title Two', minWidth : 500  }] );

Fancybox seems to ignore the options... it opens, but there is no title and the minWidth is ignored.

I'm using v2.1.5 if the fancybox javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fancybox documentation is wrong; options go inside the [group] apparently:

$.fancybox.open([{ href : '#popup_panel',  title : 'Title Two', minWidth : 500 }], [] );

Comment: Well, I don't think the documentation is wrong, I think you misinterpreted it. Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful ==>No. 10 ==> "Method two - Open fancyBox manually" for a how-to example

Comment: The issue I have with the docs is that that there is a tab (next to Api) called "Options" and then the API docs for open() says the arguments are ([group], [options]) BUT (a) the API docs do not say WHAT "options" can go in the [options] arg, and more to the point, the Options under the Options tab apparently are supposed to go in the [group] arg NOT the [options] argument. That seems like wrong docs to me.